# Kotlin: Problem with invoke() and parameterized classes

Tags: generics, kotlin

So I have an interesting problem. I have a parameterized class, Foo:

```
class Foo<T> {
    operator fun invoke(value: T) = doSomething(value) // doSomething defined elsewhere
}
```

And I want to be able to also define `invoke()` with no value if and only if T is Unit, which will call `invoke(Unit)`. I have tried defining an extension function operator fun `Foo<Unit>.invoke() = this.invoke(Unit)` outside the class, but it requires me to include an import statement wherever this extension is used, and the IDE I'm using (Android Studio) can't recognize when that extension is called using the shortcut `foo()` (it complains that `value` is missing), thus forcing me to include that import manually. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: So it basically works as you wanted with the extension function? the only problem is the missing IDE support for the import? if so: file a bug at the IDEs issue tracker...

Comment: by the way... a simple workaround for that: just write `.invoke()` and then the quick fix will import the extension function... the next quick fix applied on the `invoke` itself will then replace it with the direct call...

Answer (score 0):

You try.

```
class Foo<T> {
     fun invoke(value: T, listener: () -> Unit){
          // doSomething defined elsewhere

          listener.invoke()
     }
}
```

Comment: Not quite. I should've clarified. I actually wanted to `doSomething(Unit)` when Foo.invoke() is called (yes, including the Unit). But the particular thing I was trying to do didn't work anyway, so this question is mostly for academic curiosity now